# ggplot stat-ecdf cumulative distribution custom maximum

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, distribution

I have a df in the following format:

```
df <- read.table(text="
DAYS    STATUS    ID
 2     Complete   A
 10    Complete   A
 15    Complete   B
 NA    Incomplete A
 NA    Incomplete B
 20    Complete   C", header=TRUE)
```

I have plotted the cumulative distribution using:

```
  ggplot(df,aes(x=DAYS, color=ID)) +
  stat_ecdf(geom = "step")
```

[image]

Since this is only plotting the completed rows I would like to include the incomplete rows that have an NA for days. By doing this the cumulative distributions for each ID would not reach 100% because some of the rows do not have a value for days.

```
ID   PERCENT_COMPLETE
A         .95
B         .55
C         .5
```

For example in my full dataset ID A has .95 status complete so the distribution line would reach at max at .95 while B would reach a max at .55.

Comment: Why did you delete your original question and repost? The percentages you posted don't match the data you posted.

Comment: I wanted to add more examples for clarity, the percentages are for the full dataset not the example I posted.

Comment: Well, if the percentages and images aren't for the data you posted, it's not that helpful since we can't test with that. Feel free to add more data if you think that's necessary. But I don't see how this is any different than your original question or what was wrong with the solution I posted previously when used on the example data.

Comment: The actual data is far too large to post here. I gave a short example to get across the format of the data. The image is from the actual data and the solution you posted did not work on the full dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear any of the plotting functions handle NA values in the way you want. So we can just pre-calculate the values in the way we want using `dplyr`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df <- read.table(text="
DAYS    STATUS    ID
 2     Complete   A
 10    Complete   A
 15    Complete   B
 NA    Incomplete A
 NA    Incomplete B
 20    Complete   C", header=TRUE)

incomplete_cdf <- function(x, gmin, gmax) {
  cdf <- rle(sort(na.omit(x)))
  obsx <- cdf$values
  obsy <- cumsum(cdf$lengths)/length(x)
  data.frame(x = c(gmin, obsx, gmax) , y=c(0, obsy, tail(obsy, 1)))
}

df %>% 
  mutate(gmin =min(DAYS, na.rm=TRUE), gmax=max(DAYS, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(incomplete_cdf(DAYS, first(gmin), first(gmax)))%>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, color=ID)) +
  geom_step()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I need to add to.numeric into the rle(sort) but it works now.

Comment: Just adding `as.numeric` seems a bit troublesome. Was your `DAYS` column not already numeric? If not, something may have gone wrong when you imported your data and you'll want to find out what that is. If the column is a factor, then the `as.numeric` will be very problematic when printing the results.

Comment: It is a difftime type as I am using ceiling() to calculate it